# groupby on NaN-only column gives IndexError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, nan

The following gives IndexError: index out of bounds:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2016-10-11', 1: '2016-10-11', 2: '2016-10-11', 3: '2016-10-11', 4: '2016-10-11',5: '2016-10-11'}, 'Stock': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'ABC', 2: 'ABC', 3: 'ABC', 4: 'ABC', 5: 'XYZ'}, 'StartTime': {0: '08:00:00.241', 1: '08:00:00.243', 2: '12:34:23.563', 3: '08:14.05.908', 4: '18:54:50.100', 5: '10:08:36.657'}, 'EndTime': {0: nan,1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan}})

df1.groupby(['Stock','EndTime']).head(1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/users/.../egg_cache/p/pandas-0.16.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 994, in head
   in_head = self._cumcount_array() < n
File "/users/.../egg_cache/p/pandas-0.16.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1034, in _cumcount_array
   arr = np.arange(self.grouper._max_groupsize, dtype='int64')
File "pandas/src/properties.pyx", line 34, in pandas.lib.cache_readonly.__get__ (pandas/lib.c:41917)
File "/users/.../egg_cache/p/pandas-0.16.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1343, in _max_groupsize
   if self.indices:
File "pandas/src/properties.pyx", line 34, in pandas.lib.cache_readonly.__get__ (pandas/lib.c:41917)
File "/users/.../egg_cache/p/pandas-0.16.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1309, in indices
    return _get_indices_dict(label_list, keys)
File "/users/.../egg_cache/p/pandas-0.16.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 3767, in _get_indices_dict
    return lib.indices_fast(sorter, group_index, keys, sorted_labels)
File "pandas/lib.pyx", line 1385, in pandas.lib.indices_fast (pandas/lib.c:23875)
File "pandas/src/util.pxd", line 41, in util.get_value_at (pandas/lib.c:62901)
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

However if I exclude all NaN column it works fine as follows:

```
df1.groupby(['Stock','Date']).head(1)
         Date  EndTime     StartTime Stock
0  2016-10-11      NaN  08:00:00.241   ABC
5  2016-10-11      NaN  10:08:36.657   XYZ
```

Any idea, if this is a bug in Pandas or am I missing something here. I am reading following: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11016 
If its a bug, any suggestions for a workaround, assuming getting rid of all Nan columns is not an option.

**Some more interesting observations:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2016-10-11', 1: '2016-10-11', 2: '2016-10-11', 3: '2016-10-11', 4: '2016-10-11',5: '2016-10-11'}, 'Stock': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'ABC', 2: 'ABC', 3: 'ABC', 4: 'ABC', 5: 'XYZ'}, 'StartTime': {0: '08:00:00.241', 1: '08:00:00.243', 2: '12:34:23.563', 3: '08:14.05.908', 4: '18:54:50.100', 5: '10:08:36.657'}, 'EndTime': {0: nan,1: nan, 2: 1, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan}})

print df1
         Date  EndTime     StartTime Stock
0  2016-10-11      NaN  08:00:00.241   ABC
1  2016-10-11      NaN  08:00:00.243   ABC
2  2016-10-11        1  12:34:23.563   ABC
3  2016-10-11      NaN  08:14.05.908   ABC
4  2016-10-11      NaN  18:54:50.100   ABC
5  2016-10-11      NaN  10:08:36.657   XYZ

df1.groupby(['Stock','EndTime']).head(1)
         Date  EndTime     StartTime Stock
0  2016-10-11      NaN  08:00:00.241   ABC
2  2016-10-11        1  12:34:23.563   ABC
```

The above output looks incorrect to me. Shouldn't it be:

```
         Date  EndTime     StartTime Stock
0  2016-10-11      NaN  08:00:00.241   ABC
2  2016-10-11        1  12:34:23.563   ABC
5  2016-10-11      NaN  10:08:36.657   XYZ
```

Now for the following case:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2016-10-11', 1: '2016-10-11', 2: '2016-10-11', 3: '2016-10-11', 4: '2016-10-11',5: '2016-10-11'}, 'Stock': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'ABC', 2: 'ABC', 3: 'ABC', 4: 'ABC', 5: 'XYZ'}, 'StartTime': {0: '08:00:00.241', 1: '08:00:00.243', 2: '12:34:23.563', 3: '08:14.05.908', 4: '18:54:50.100', 5: '10:08:36.657'}, 'EndTime': {0: nan,1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: 1}})

print df1
         Date  EndTime     StartTime Stock
0  2016-10-11      NaN  08:00:00.241   ABC
1  2016-10-11      NaN  08:00:00.243   ABC
2  2016-10-11      NaN  12:34:23.563   ABC
3  2016-10-11      NaN  08:14.05.908   ABC
4  2016-10-11      NaN  18:54:50.100   ABC
5  2016-10-11        1  10:08:36.657   XYZ

df1.groupby(['Stock','EndTime']).head(1)
         Date  EndTime     StartTime Stock
0  2016-10-11      NaN  08:00:00.241   ABC
5  2016-10-11        1  10:08:36.657   XYZ
```

This one is fine.

Comment: `df1.groupby(['Stock','EndTime']).head(1)` (for the very first `df1`) works fine for me (Pandas 0.19.0)

Comment: Mine is 0.16.2. Unfortunately getting versions updated in corporate setting might take longer. so seeking a workaround.

Comment: @MaxU can you share the output in all three cases that you are getting using 0.19.0. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul, here is the output of your code when using Pandas 0.19.0:

```
In [5]: df1
Out[5]:
         Date  EndTime     StartTime Stock
0  2016-10-11      NaN  08:00:00.241   ABC
1  2016-10-11      NaN  08:00:00.243   ABC
2  2016-10-11      NaN  12:34:23.563   ABC
3  2016-10-11      NaN  08:14.05.908   ABC
4  2016-10-11      NaN  18:54:50.100   ABC
5  2016-10-11      NaN  10:08:36.657   XYZ

In [6]: df1.groupby(['Stock','EndTime']).head(1)
Out[6]:
         Date  EndTime     StartTime Stock
0  2016-10-11      NaN  08:00:00.241   ABC

In [7]: df1.groupby(['Stock','Date']).head(1)
Out[7]:
         Date  EndTime     StartTime Stock
0  2016-10-11      NaN  08:00:00.241   ABC
5  2016-10-11      NaN  10:08:36.657   XYZ

In [8]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2016-10-11', 1: '2016-10-11', 2: '2016-10-11', 3: '2016-10-11', 4: '2016-10-11',5: '2016-10-11'}, 'Stock': {
   ...: 0: 'ABC', 1: 'ABC', 2: 'ABC', 3: 'ABC', 4: 'ABC', 5: 'XYZ'}, 'StartTime': {0: '08:00:00.241', 1: '08:00:00.243', 2: '12:34:23.563', 3: '08:14
   ...: .05.908', 4: '18:54:50.100', 5: '10:08:36.657'}, 'EndTime': {0: nan,1: nan, 2: 1, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan}})
   ...:

In [9]: df1.groupby(['Stock','EndTime']).head(1)
Out[9]:
         Date  EndTime     StartTime Stock
0  2016-10-11      NaN  08:00:00.241   ABC
2  2016-10-11      1.0  12:34:23.563   ABC

In [10]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2016-10-11', 1: '2016-10-11', 2: '2016-10-11', 3: '2016-10-11', 4: '2016-10-11',5: '2016-10-11'}, 'Stock':
    ...: {0: 'ABC', 1: 'ABC', 2: 'ABC', 3: 'ABC', 4: 'ABC', 5: 'XYZ'}, 'StartTime': {0: '08:00:00.241', 1: '08:00:00.243', 2: '12:34:23.563', 3: '08:
    ...: 14.05.908', 4: '18:54:50.100', 5: '10:08:36.657'}, 'EndTime': {0: nan,1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: 1}})
    ...:

In [11]: df1.groupby(['Stock','EndTime']).head(1)
Out[11]:
         Date  EndTime     StartTime Stock
0  2016-10-11      NaN  08:00:00.241   ABC
5  2016-10-11      1.0  10:08:36.657   XYZ
```

Comment: Thanks @MaxU. I think there should be one more row for Stock XYZ in Out[6]?

Comment: @Rahul, why do you think so?

Comment: Likewise in Out[9]. Am I missing on something?

Comment: `groupby` should be by each unique combination of `'Stock'` and `EndTime`. In case of `Out[6]` these are `'ABC' - NaN` and `'XYZ'-NaN`. Then `head(1)` gets first row from such groupings.